# Mathematically I have enough power but the power source don't seem like enough

Tags: power-supply, voltage, power, watts

Lets say i want to reach a certain wattage of 2,500 W. But I run it off a power source which maxes out at 5 A and 20 V. But I step the voltage up to 500 using a coil or transformer and now 5A × 500V is 2,500 but thats a lot of power from a small power source. Is stepping the voltage up really going to allow me to get 2,500 W of power from 5 A and 20 V or am I calculating this wrong? I'm new to electrical engineering and it seem strang that I can have such a power increase just by increasing voltage/amps.

Comment: By stepping up voltage, you stepping-down the current. It's conservation of energy.

Comment: Make sense. So you can get a ridiculous power increase but you have to sacrifice either voltage or current.

Comment: You can't get more out power than you put in. You can (theoretically) increase the voltage OR current to whatever you want. But the second value will drop, such that the above principle is not violated.

Comment: So if i am using an appliance that require a cetain amount of power "Watts" but my power source isn't powerful enough but i decrease lets say current to increase the volts so i reach that power supply, your saying it still will not work cause even though i have the wattage needed by steping volts up and steping current down it power will still remain the same?

Comment: @EugeneSh. Just to add to this, it's probably more accurate to say you cant get out more energy than you put in. For a constant output, this is the same as what you said, but many devices exploit the fact that you can store energy in the circuit (in capacitors and inductors), which allows you to briefly output very high power levels given a low power input.

Comment: No, it won't work. The appliance will try to draw more current that the supply can provide. So it will either kill the supply or drop the voltage down, so the appliance won't work.

Comment: I see. Thats kind of what i thought as well. Just seem werid cause the numbers match but the power source didn't

Comment: @BeB00 Right. One can store a low power output over long time, but then output it over a shorter time, so the power during that time will be higher than the one used to charge.

Comment: Maybe it will work for a second but after that i will drop

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your 20 V, 5 A supply is capable of 100 Watts of power (V x I). You cannot get more *power* from the supply, whatever you do.

You can, however, convert the voltage. In the case of AC, you use a transformer. In the case of DC, there are many different conversion methods.

**But**, the maximum output power must always be 100 W! So, if you convert to 10 V, you can only get 10 A. If you convert to 1 V, then you can have 100 A. But the power won't increase. V x I can't exceed the original 100 W.

In the real world, each conversion will also have some inefficiency. So you'll actually end up with less power than you started with.

Answer (score 1):

> am i calculating this wrong?

Yep! By stepping up the *voltage* with a transformer you will still only get the same amount of *power* out. There's no free lunch. In this case, the *current* you can draw will be less, by the same ratio.